# Presto query performance via Hue on AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-emr, presto, hue

I am currently trying to setup Presto connection trough Hue on an AWS EMR Cluster (release 5.24.0).

By default, AWS is setting the connection using the `jdbc` interface.
The problem of using this interface is that for some reason it loads only the first 1000 records when performing a query of the type

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

Which is probably due to a current Hue limitation that hardcodes the fetchsize to 1000 rows and cannot be edited.

According to Hue's documentation, however, it is advisable to use `sqlalchemy` as interface instead of jdbc whenever possible. So I changed the presto interpreter settings and installed pyhive as documented in the guide.

The fetchsize problem is gone, but even performing a

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table
```

can take several minutes. Moreover, from the Hue UI, the query seems to be completed, when it is still running if I look at the Presto UI.

What is worse is that if I submit a new query in the Hue Presto editor, the new query is submitted, but the previous one keeps running.

Has anyone experienced similar issues? Does changing some Hue/Presto/Hive settings improve anything?

Comment: I hear from people that it isn't easy to use Hue with Presto. Would you consider one of the apps that are known to support Presto (https://prestosql.io/resources.html#guis)?

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen I can definitely consider to use an alternate UI, but only as a last resort. We are trying to use only applications that are provided and managed by AWS with the minimum necessary configuration changes.

Comment: Hue sends a close_statement to the previous query when submitting a new one. This could be checked in the new Chrome Network Ajax tab to be successful. I looked at https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/desktop/libs/notebook/src/notebook/connectors/sql_alchemy.py#L238 and it looks good. To be fair, connector was mostly tested via AWS Athena so far, but it is open to contributions

Comment: You can also consider https://redash.io which is very easy to use and not that costly.